# Windows 10 Customize start screen tile not working

Tags: windows-10-preview, tiles

Follow all the steps of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx) help to customize the tile on windows 10 for desktop application but Windows 10 is not showing any tiles after complete all steps from the msdn help.

Steps followed:
1) Create the manifest file start with my Appname **"Connect.VisualElementsManifest.xml"**

```
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <VisualElements
        BackgroundColor="#FF0000"
        ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="on"
        ForegroundText="light"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Connect.150.png"
        Square70x70Logo="Assets\Connect.70.png"/>
</Application>
```

2) Place **.xml** at executable location, copy Assets folder at executable location. 

3) Run the powershell command `"(ls "$env:programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\Connect.lnk").lastwritetime = get-date"` 

4) Found the event 28032 in Event viewer with failure reason NULL. 

5) After all the steps tiles NOT showing on start screen. 

6) Using same steps and xml, Tiles successfully shown on Windows 8.1 but somehow it not working on Windows 10 
Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What build are you using?  If you are not using the current build, go ahead and upgrade, no point in trying to do something the build you have can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been known that this functionality is broken since the build 9926, as reported by the community and first encountered by OblyTile. I hope Microsoft acknowledge this and fix it before Windows 10 RTM.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidPostill This looks like it could be accepted as a question until the issue is fixed in Windows 10. As of build 10240 (ostensibly the RTM), tile customization as described by Microsoft still doesn't work.